# Debug Current Instruction Pointer, trying to add values of three textviews

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

Here i am trying to add values of 3 textviews and then show in another textview using button onClickListener(),but whenever i click on Button, everytime getting, unfortunately app has stopped with below Logcat please the problem and provide some solution, 
Logcat Report

```
10-13 17:48:40.440: E/Trace(703): error opening trace file: 
No such file or directory (2)
10-13 17:48:41.080: D/dalvikvm(703): 
GC_CONCURRENT freed 65K, 2% free 8362K/8519K,  paused 35ms+30ms, total 214ms
10-13 17:48:41.080: D/gralloc_goldfish(703): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-13 17:49:01.316: I/Choreographer(703): Skipped 31 frames!  
The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-13 17:50:16.511: I/Choreographer(703): Skipped 31 frames!  
The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-13 17:50:35.430: D/AndroidRuntime(703): Shutting down VM
10-13 17:50:35.430: W/dalvikvm(703): threadid=1: 
thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
10-13 17:50:35.450: E/AndroidRuntime(703): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 17:50:35.450: E/AndroidRuntime(703): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-13 17:50:35.450: E/AndroidRuntime(703): 
at com.suvendu.tutorial.cb.CheckBoxTutorialActivity$1.onClick
(CheckBoxTutorialActivity.java:88)
10-13 17:50:35.450: E/AndroidRuntime(703):  
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
10-13 17:50:35.450: E/AndroidRuntime(703): 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
10-13 17:50:35.450: E/AndroidRuntime(703): 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-13 17:50:35.450: E/AndroidRuntime(703):  
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-13 17:50:35.450: E/AndroidRuntime(703):  
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-13 17:50:35.450: E/AndroidRuntime(703):
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-13 17:50:35.450: E/AndroidRuntime(703):
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 17:50:35.450: E/AndroidRuntime(703):   
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-13 17:50:35.450: E/AndroidRuntime(703):  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-13 17:50:35.450: E/AndroidRuntime(703):  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-13 17:50:35.450: E/AndroidRuntime(703):
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Activity Code:-

```
    Integer c;
Integer y;
Integer z;
Integer a;

    btn_total_code=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_total);
    btn_total_code.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
   {
   public void onClick (View  v) { 
    c=Integer.parseInt(text_price_regular_code.getText().toString());
    y=Integer.parseInt(text_price_regular_code.getText().toString()); 
    z=Integer.parseInt(text_price_regular_code.getText().toString());   
    a=c+y+z;
    text_total_code.setText(Integer.toString(a)); 
    }

    });
```

Comment: You have asked this question four times, using 2 different user IDs.  You should not just keep recreating the same question.  Please, please, please just use on of the existing ones.  This is the equivalent of spam and you are abusing the community.  http://stackoverflow.com/users/1736992/user1736992

Comment: Sorry, Simon for the yesterday incident, but friend i am not getting the exact problem, and really i like stackoverflow and i believe that only stackoverflow is a place where i can find answers of my each and every questions, i knew that you will see my post, and will comment me definetely, but think also, i has not change any value, because i like actually, i hate fake, here i am using simple a button to get addition of three values nothing else, if i will use these code in separate activity then it works but when i use these few lines of code in my complete then i am getting problem, sorry.

Comment: OK, do you promise you will not open the same question again, only work with this one?  If so, then I will help you.

Comment: my friend, i also don't wanted to create a new account, but you know my previous account has been cancelled, so i have no way to connect with you to say sorry and i appreciate your helping nature,yesterday i thought i did wrong with you and i need to say sorry personally, to you because yesterday i have mistaken by use that kind of treat,  therefore i just want to forget previous talks and i also requesting you please please please please number of times forgive me, be a friend answer is not important for me, mankindness is above then all

Comment: We should move this to chat because there will need to be a lot of questions...http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/17964/debug-current-instruction-pointer?tab=general

Comment: i want to connect you via chat but getting You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here.

Comment: i have 3 checkboxes and 3 textviews, i am doing whenever user will click on each and every checkbox then name of checkbox and value of matched textview will shown in 2 another textviews one for checkbox name and second for textview value, like:- product name and its price, now when user want to calculate total amount need to pay there i am providing button Get Total once user will click on button then price need to show in total textview, and here i am fetching textview values from xml file, using textview widget and able to show but not able to show total amount to pay, also using qty edittxt

Answer (score 0):

As we can't use chat, I don't know how to help you.  I'm sorry.  The code you posted works fine, I've just created a project.  The question you are asking is not an error.  You have simply hit a breakpoint in Eclipse (I assume you are using Eclipse).  My best advice is to learn how to use Eclispe, especially how to debug and how to control breakpoints.  You will not be able to create an app successfully without knowing how to do this.

Ignore this:

```
The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

It is simply because you have paused on the breakpoint.  It's not relevant.  For now, run your app using "run", not "debug", or remove the breakpoint.

[EDIT]

Sam.  You need to learn how to catch fish, instead of asking me to give you a fish every hour.

Learn to read the stack trace.  It's very simple

```
10-13 17:50:35.450: E/AndroidRuntime(703): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-13 17:50:35.450: E/AndroidRuntime(703): 
at com.suvendu.tutorial.cb.CheckBoxTutorialActivity$1.onClick
(CheckBoxTutorialActivity.java:88)
```

You have a null pointer exception in CheckBoxTutorialActivity at line 88.  Put a breakpoint on that line, run your app and see what is null and why.  If you can't figure it out, start a new question and use a precise title for the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot... and sorry again, nice to talk you, from today onward this sam will treat you as a teacher not as a friend, Sorry Teacher, i will read about eclipse and thanks for the suggestion because you are correct i am using debug not run, but next time i will try with run, hopefully it will work, and i promise i am not going to change my id and also not going to ask duplicate questions.......cu again

Comment: Simon Sir, i used run and also added this line in manifest:- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> and now i am getting error message whenever click on Get Total button :- the source attachment does not contain source for the Integer.class, what could be the reason...

Comment: Sam, many things!  Why did you add ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE?  You do not need it for what your are doing.  The "source attachment" message is simply the debugger saying that you have stopped on a line using the Integer class and it cannot find the source code for it.  You are probably trying to "step into" code using Integer instead of "step over".  However, it is nothing to do with whatever problem you are having.  Finally, do you know the difference between Integer and int?  You should be using int most of the time, not Integer.

Comment: simon sir, i agree with you, i have already deleted both the things, first ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, because in this program i don't require access to network, and secondly, i have changed int to Integer, but very frank earlier i used that by mistake, sir please see my logcat report

Comment: Sure sir, i will....thanks a lot, sorry i have taken huge time of yours, ok sir but i have learnt many things by you related to code, stackoverflow and support to everyone....bye